# Receiving an error when deploying react app to vercel

Tags: reactjs, command-line-interface, create-react-app, vercel

Having issues deploying my create-react-app project to Vercel using their dashboard. I removed all of my images from my src and am calling them like `src={"images/my-image.png"}` from my[image] public folder.

It deploys fine with no errors in my localhost. Am I needed to clear a cache somewhere? Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change `src={'string'}` to

```js
import Avatar3 from '../public/images/avatar-3.png'

...
    <Image src={Avatar3} ... />
...
```

## src

Must be one of the following:

- A statically imported image file, or
- A path string. This can be either an absolute external URL, or an internal path depending on the loader prop or loader configuration.

ref. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Comment: None of my files are imported, they are called directly from the source png

Comment: Is there a particular way vercel needs their images declared or called?